# Identifying kernel threads

Tags: linux, process

I'd like to know how I can distinguish a kernel-thread from a user-thread for a process-scanner I'm building. I'm having a hard time finding a good definition of both types.

I found that kernel-threads don't have memory of their own, so no Vm* values in /proc/$pid/status, and that a stat on /proc/$pid/exe does not return anything.

So, I figured I could identify kernel threads if a process has no Vm* values and no inode number. I figured wrong... my script sees php-cgi processes that are identified as kernel processes sometime.

If found that most of those wrongly identified processes are zombies that are gone a second later. So I implemented a simple check to see if the status is "Z". If so, ignore it.
That saved me a lot of false positives, but still I receive messages about php-cgi kernel-processes.

Can anyone tell me how I can distinguish a kernel-thread from a user-thread the right way?

Comment: Using Google I understand all kernel-threads are a child of kthreadd... but on some CentOS 5 servers I don't see a kthreadd process. I do see a kthread process but some kernel threads I see in the processlist (using ps auxf) are not a child of that process.

Comment: kernel threads by convention have names in square brackets, e.g: `[ksoftirqd/0]`. Also, by convention, a number after a slash indicates a CPU number.

Comment: I wish that was true... on my system I see a kswapd0 which in ps is listed with brackets around it. In /proc/$pid/status however, it's name has no brackets. Also, there is no slash in the name.

Comment: I think I was on to something before: On newer kernels (CentOS 6.x has 2.6.32) all kernel-threads seem to be a child of kthreadd. On older kernels (CentOS 5.x has 2.6.18) I see kernel-threads are a child of kthread (without the extra d) OR are a child of init. It would be nice if someone could confirm this though. :-)

Answer (score 15):

There *are* some visible differences between a kernel thread and a user-space thread:

- `/proc/$pid/cmdline` is empty for kernel threads - this is the method used by `ps` and `top` to distinguish kernel threads.
- The `/proc/$pid/exe` symbolic link has no target for kernel threads - which makes sense since they do not have a corresponding executable on the filesystem.

  More specifically, the [`readlink()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/readlink) system call returns `ENOENT` (*"No such file or directory"*), despite the fact that the link itself exists, to denote the fact that the executable for this process does not exist (and never did).

  Therefore, a reliable way to check for kernel threads should be to call `readlink()` on `/proc/$pid/exe` and check its return code. If it succeeds then `$pid` is a user process. If it fails with `ENOENT`, then an extra `stat()` on `/proc/$pid/exe` should tell apart the case of a kernel thread from a process that has just terminated.
- `/proc/$pid/status` is missing several fields for *most* kernel threads - more specifically a few fields related to virtual memory.

Comment: In my original post you see that the virtual memory related lines in /proc/$pid/status cannot be trusted as processes that are shutting down don't have those as well. That is the biggest part of my problem... :-P
I'll look into /proc/$pid/cmdline, but since some processes rewrite that I don't think its a very good idea to rely on that.

Comment: @HighKing: True, `cmdline` can be affected by threads changing `argv[0]`, although I am not sure if it can become completely empty. So I found another difference for you :-)

Comment: The /proc/$pid/exe I had already found, see my first post. ;-)
Well, I've added a check on /proc/$pid/cmdline, so am now checking if cmdline is empty, if there's no VmSize and if a stat on exe returns zero results. Still I get php-cgi processes that are identified as kernel-threads. :-P

Comment: @HighKing: uh, 1 sec... if you do a `stat` on `/proc/$pid/exe` and the executable is removed it will error-out, since `stat` will attempt to dereference the link. What you need is to check the output of `readlink(2)`...

Comment: I don't know... they are gone 1/10th of a second later so I don't have the time to check the ps output.

I guess I'll just have to recheck all kernel threads at the end of the loop. Not very efficient, but it's better this.

Edit: Damn you're fast... ;-)

Comment: So, if readlink works: user thread else: kernel thread?
And if readlink doesn't work but there is a VmSize: biiiig problem? :)

Comment: @HighKing: `readlink()` will work for kernel threads too, but it will return an empty link target. *That* is what you would have to check for...

Comment: Kernel threads may also use virtual memory. `Vm*` fields are not unique to userspace threads.

Comment: Using readlink seems to be a bit of a problem. Readlink seems to fail in my perl-script on kernel-threads as well. Also, in bash the readlink command returns status 1 on a kernel-thread. :(

Comment: @HighKing: have a look at the actual return code. `readlink` on kernel threads returns ENOENT, which is pretty specific, considering that the actual link *does* exist...

Comment: Hmm, the perl readlink-function returns "No such file or directory" on /proc/2/exe. On /proc/idontexist/exe I also get "No such file or directory". Not really something I can rely on I guess. :-(

Comment: @HighKing: Uh, no... the *kernel* returns ENOENT (= "No such file or directory") for readlink on the `/proc/$pid/exe` of a kernel thread. Makes sense, since no executable ever existed.

Comment: @HighKing: I think that you can rely on using ENOENT, as long as you stat the link again *after* readlink, to catch terminating processes...

Comment: OK, I simply created an extra (-l /proc/$pid/exe) check for this. Too bad we have to use a workaround for this but if it works I'm happy with it. :)

Comment: @HighKing: make sure to do the final `-l` check *after* calling readlink, to avoid issues with terminating processes...

Comment: I did, but it didn't solve my problem. I don't have anymore time to spend on this issue for the next few weeks. I'll get back when I have the time to proceed.

Comment: Could you mention the specifics of the false positives? You get `ENOENT` from readlink, the link itself exists, yet those are not kernel threads?

Comment: Yep. I have php-cgi processes that are identified as kernel threads. The link indeed exists while readlink errors out.

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late reply (was on vacation for 2 weeks).
The readlink errors out with "No such file or directory" in the $! variable (I don't think I can see if it was truly ENOENT with perl, can I?)

Comment: Hmm, the last few php-cgi kernel processes my script found all have state "R". This does not comply with my theory that those processes are shutting down when my script tries to check them.

Comment: @HighKing What about [checking the task flags](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56369641/427158) then?

Comment: @maxschlepzig, this question I asked over 8 years ago. Do do not work for the company where I needed this so I'm not really going to seek a rhel 5 machine to check if that works. ;)

Answer (score 5):

As you pointed out in your own comment above, all user processes are descendants of the init process (pid=1). Kernel threads are not descendants of the init process, since init is a user process, and user processes cannot create kernel threads. Therefore, to check if process p is a user process and not a kernel thread, one needs to operate on the process graph and evaluate if `init dom p` where dom is the [Dominator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominator_%28graph_theory%29) operator. Concretely in Python:

```
def is_user_process(p):
  if (p=='1'):
    print 'User process'
  else:
    pstat = open('/proc/%s/stat'%p).read().split()
    parent = pstat[3]
    if (parent=='1'):
      print 'User process'
    elif (parent=='0'):
      print 'Kernel thread'
    else:
      is_user_process(parent)
```

Comment: There are simpler and faster alternatives - i.e. [checking the process flags](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56369641/427158) or checking if [PPID equals 2](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/411175/1131).

Answer (score 3):

You can read thread `flags` value from `/proc/[pid]/stat` ([see proc(5) manpage](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html)) and check if it has `PF_KTHREAD` bit flag set.

`PF_KTHREAD` constant itself has been [available since 2.6.17](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/7b34e4283c685f5cc6ba6d30e939906eee0d4bcf), which is roughly for 10 years, and it's value [hasn't changed since then](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.2-rc2/ident/PF_KTHREAD):

```
#define PF_KTHREAD      0x00200000  /* I am a kernel thread */
```

Even through the header file containing this constant (`include/linux/sched.h`) is not exported to userspace, having a copy of this definition in your source code combined with kernel version check done from userspace at runtime (e.g. using [uname(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/uname.2.html) system call) should be pretty robust.

Comment: Similar answer to similar question: [How to identify a thread is a kernel thread or not through `bash`?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61940790/427158)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a version that works under bash:

```
# check if pid is user process and not a kernel thread
is_user_process() {
  if [[ $1 -eq 1 ]]; then
    return 0
  else
    parent=$(grep -e '^PPid:' /proc/$1/status | cut -c6-)
    if [[ $parent -eq 1 ]]; then
      return 0
    elif [[ $parent -eq 0 ]]; then
      return 1
    else
      is_user_process $parent
    fi
  fi
}
```

To use it do

```
~$ is_user_process `pgrep kthreadd` || echo "kthreadd is kernel process"
```

This was first useful solution for me at least, thanks for er0  of the python version.