# What is the most general way to list all the kernel tasks in a linux system?

Tags: c, linux, shell, linux-kernel, kernel-module

I am trying to figure out the best way to write a cross platform kernel code/shell script to list all the kernel task `{(pid/tid , name)}` in a `linux` dis. machine. it should be the most general possible. I tried to use `ps -T` but it is seems to be inaccurate and some platform don't support it in their `busybox`. Any suggestions?

Comment: Just a suggestion , try `top` may be that can work... http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?top

Comment: Pipe with a UNIX command like ps?

Comment: I have a feeling, aside from writing your own C code to list all processes, you will have to rely on tools that may or may not be available in the particular distribution. If someone has a better answer, I'm all ears.

Comment: I agree with 'Pipe + ps'. Is your concern that different platforms have different options available in ps? With some research, you should be able to boil it down to a lowest-common-demoniator set. Good luck.

Comment: Check this out:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14005599/for-each-process-does-it-iterate-over-the-threads-and-the-processes-as-well

or use `ps`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to distinguish user processes from kernel tasks, then this is a previous discussion on the subject: [Identifying kernel threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12213445/identifying-kernel-threads/13984231#13984231)

My answer to that question does not require any tools, it simply reads the contents of /proc//stat, so it should work on any distribution.

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
ps -e -o pgrp= -o pid= -o cmd= | sed -ne 's/^ *0 *// p'
```

although it assumes all kernel tasks belong to process group 0.