# for_each_process - Does it iterate over the threads and the processes as well?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, embedded-linux

I would like to iterate all the tasks in the kernel (threads and processes) and print tid/pid and name using for_each_process macro:

```
#define for_each_process(p) \
    for (p = &init_task ; (p = next_task(p)) != &init_task ; )
```

How can I distinguish between thread and process?

So I'll print it like that:

```
 if (p->real_parent->pid == NULL)
      printk("PROCESS: name: %s pid: %d \n",p->comm,p->pid);
 else
      printk("THREAD: name: %s tid: %d \n",p->comm,p->pid);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following macros are what you need:

```
/*
 * Careful: do_each_thread/while_each_thread is a double loop so
 *          'break' will not work as expected - use goto instead.
 */
#define do_each_thread(g, t) \
        for (g = t = &init_task ; (g = t = next_task(g)) != &init_task ; ) do

#define while_each_thread(g, t) \
        while ((t = next_thread(t)) != g)
```

Use them like this:

```
        rcu_read_lock();
        do_each_thread(g, t) {
            //...
        } while_each_thread(g, t);

        rcu_read_unlock();
```

Comment: Does `do_each_thread(g, t) {...} while_each_thread(g, t);` construct need to be executed under `tasklist_lock`, or RCU read-side lock is enough? As far as I can see [in the kernel sources](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/ident?i=do_each_thread), such blocks are usually executed with `tasklist_lock` locked. The OOM killer seems to be an exception, is uses RCU as you suggest. So, could you explain how to use such constructs correctly?

Comment: (continued) If `tasklist_lock` is needed, this would make it difficult to use `do_each_thread(g, t) {...} while_each_thread(g, t);` in the kernel modules (`tasklist_lock` is not exported). Still, it can be necessary sometimes to implement traversal of the collection of threads in a kernel module. Another reason to find out, if `tasklist_lock` is really needed there.

Comment: Well, I have looked through the code of these macros and other relevent places recently. It seems that all the operations with the lists involved there are written in an RCU-aware way. So, if is it OK for one's code to see a bit stale data sometimes and the code only reads the data from the list but does not change them, RCU read-side lock should be enough indeed.