# How to identify a thread is a kernel thread or not through `bash`?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, linux-kernel

How to identify a thread is a kernel thread or not through `bash`?

I found that you could identify the kernel thread by `ps`: if the thread name is enclosed in `[]`, it's a kernel thread. But i do not think it is a good solution.

I would be thankful for any hint on this question.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. SO is a question and answer page for professional and enthusiastic programmers. Add your own code to your question. You are expected to show at least the amount of research you have put into solving this question yourself.

Comment: I would follow your advice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can determine whether a particular task is a kthread or not by looking at `/proc/<PID>/stat`. More presicesely, according to [`man 5 proc`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html) the 9th field of this virtual file contains the kernel flags for the process. In case of a kthread, the flags will have [`PF_KTHREAD`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.6.14/source/include/linux/sched.h#L1477) set.

Here's an example of a Bash script that takes a PID as argument and checks if it's a kthread or not:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

read -a stats < /proc/$1/stat
flags=${stats[8]}

if (( ($flags & 0x00200000) == 0x00200000 )); then
    echo 'KTHREAD'
else
    echo 'NOT KTHREAD'
fi
```

This isn't really simpler than just doing `ps u -p <PID>` and checking for `[]`, but it's a pure Bash solution nonetheless.

---

There are also some more "tricks" which can be used to identify a kernel thread, it's easy to modify the above script to use one of the methods highlighted in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12231039/3889449).